# .NET : Closing the application gracefully on user logout

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, application-close

We have VB.NET windows application installed on our client's machine. Some of our client used third party softwares (like imprivata badge) to log user out. Is there any way to gracefully close our VB.NET windows application when user logs out by using these third party softwares? Can VB.NET windows application know/ gets message that the user is logging out?

Comment: You could look at the `SystemEvents.SessionEnding` event.